# Call Preload Function

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preload Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059587/preload-function)

that is my js code. https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js

```
   preload : function() {
            $('.slidesContainer').css({
                backgroundImage: "url(img/loading.gif)",
                backgroundPosition: "50% 50%",
                backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
            });

            this._loadImage( this.slides.eq( this.options.startAtSlide - 1 ).attr("src") ).then( $.proxy(function( url ) {
          this.slidesControl.fadeIn( this.options.fade.interval );
            this._trigger( "loaded", this.options.startAtSlide, this );

        },this));
    },
```

How I can use this code. I am call so $("#slides").slides("preload");. But If I am using $("#slides").slides(); before $("#slides").slides("preload"); that is works. How I can call only preload.?

Thanks..

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It doesn't make any sense. It's a jQuery plugin, and until you've run the ".slides()" main initialization routine the other methods can't possibly work.

Comment: Ok Kling I am sorry. But I ask the questions, since more than 4 days. No answer :(

Comment: Pointy I want make, images upload after add in the slider. I am adding but not show slider.

Comment: @cmpone: Repeating the question will not help you. As I said, instead, provide as much information as possible. Describe your setup, what the result should be, what you have tried, etc. The more information you give, the easier it is for us to help you. Provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with which we can play.

Answer (score 0):

Since slider is a widget you cannot call `preload` directly without creating the instance of it which is done by `$("#slides").slides();`. You can have call it before calling `preload` to make it work.